# How to get the parse values?

Tags: xcode, json, ios5, nsdictionary

i am writing the code below manner.

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
    JSONObjectWithData:responseData 
 options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@",json);
```

The printed dictionary is

```
(
        {
        Contents =         (
                        {
                Id = 2;
                LastUpdated = "/Date(1338048712847+0000)/";
                Title = "Webinar: HP & MS solutions for Mid-Market";
                Url = "http://infra2apps.blob.core.windows.net/content/VMMM019-HP-MS_MidMarket.wmv";
            },
                        {
                Id = 1;
                LastUpdated = "/Date(1338048712773+0000)/";
                Title = "Webinar: Private Cloud with HP & MS";
                Url = "http://infra2apps.blob.core.windows.net/content/VMPC012-HPMS_PrivateCloud.wmv";
            }
        );
        Id = 1;
        ImageUrl = "http://infra2apps.blob.core.windows.net/eventapp/black-microsoft-logo.jpg";
        Name = "Unified Communications & Collaborations";
        Sessions =         (
                        {
                Description = "Microsoft Lync delivers Unified Communication to help People connect in new ways, anytime, anywhere. Learn how HP and Microsoft are helping customers transform their business infrastrucutre and gain greater productivity by making every communication an interaction that is more collaborative and engaging.";
                EndDate = "/Date(1275822000000+0000)/";
                FriendlyName = TB3257;
                Id = 1;
                Location = "Building N-4105";
                Speakers =                 (
                                        {
                        Company = Microsoft;
                        Email = "johndoe@microsoft.com";
                        Name = "John Doe";
                        Title = "Group Manager";
                    }
                );
                StartDate = "/Date(1275818400000+0000)/";
                Title = "Connecting People in New Ways with Microsoft Lync";
            },
                        {
                Description = "Microsoft Lync delivers Unified Communication to help People connect in new ways, anytime, anywhere. Learn how HP and Microsoft are helping customers transform their business infrastrucutre and gain greater productivity by making every communication an interaction that is more collaborative and engaging.";
                EndDate = "/Date(1275825600000+0000)/";
                FriendlyName = TB3258;
                Id = 2;
                Location = "Building N-4105";
                Speakers =                 (
                                        {
                        Company = HP;
                        Email = "janedoe@hp.com";
                        Name = "Jane Doe";
                        Title = "Vice President";
                    },
                                        {
                        Company = Microsoft;
                        Email = "johndoe@microsoft.com";
                        Name = "John Doe";
                        Title = "Group Manager";
                    }
                );
                StartDate = "/Date(1275822000000+0000)/";
                Title = "Connecting People in New Ways with Microsoft Lync - Part 2";
            }
        );
    },
```

....etc

And then store the content values into another dictionary after that i store into an array.
the below code is to store the array id

```
   NSDictionary *boothmenucontents = [json valueForKey: @"Contents"]; 
  NSMutableArray *dictResponseboothmenucontentsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: boothmenucontents,nil];
 for(int i = 0; i<[dictResponseboothmenucontentsArray count]; i++)

    {
        NSMutableArray *IdArrayboothmenucontentes=[[dictResponseboothmenucontentsArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Id"];

        NSLog(@"id array is %@",IdArrayboothmenucontentes);
        for(int k=0;k<[IdArrayboothmenucontentes count];k++)
        {
            NSString * strcontentId= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[IdArrayboothmenucontentes objectAtIndex:k]]; 

            NSLog(@"strcontentId%@",strcontentId);
            label.text=strcontentId;
            [boothmenuidarrayvalues addObject:strcontentId];


            NSLog(@"%@",boothmenuidarrayvalues);

        }


    }
```

finally i print the boothmenuidarrayvalues

it print like this

```
  "(\n    2,\n    1\n)",
    "(\n    4,\n    3\n)",
    "(\n    6,\n    5\n)",
    "(\n    8,\n    7\n)",
    "(\n    10,\n    9\n)",
    "(\n    12,\n    11\n)"
```

but  i want to print content id only once but it print in a row in two times.
May be i follow a wrong method please tell me how to give own root for that response.

Please help me.......

Comment: can u print IdArrayboothmenucontentes ..?

Comment: @safecase yes but it takes two id values at atime

Comment: Try this : NSDictionary *boothmenucontents = [json valueForKey: @"Contents"]; 
  NSMutableArray *dictResponseboothmenucontentsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: boothmenucontents,nil];
 for(int i = 0; i<[dictResponseboothmenucontentsArray count]; i++)

    {[boothmenuidarrayvalues addObject:[[dictResponseboothmenucontentsArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Id"];}

Comment: @safecase it is also same as my program output

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps It will help you.

```
NSMutableArray *contenstsArray = [contentsDictionary ValueForKey:@"Contents"]; //Suppose you already brought all the json data into contentsDictionary
NSMutableArray *idArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSMutableDictionary *idDic in contenstsArray) {
   NSString *idString = [idDic valueForKey:@"Id"];
   [idArray addObject:];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line looks wrong:

```
NSMutableArray *IdArrayboothmenucontentes=[[dictResponseboothmenucontentsArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Id"];
```

I'm not sure what you are expecting it to do, but what it looks like it does is grab the ith object in the dictResponseboothmenucontentsArray, which is a dictionary and then gets the object in that dictionary with the key "Id", which is an number, so IdArrayboothmenucontentes now contains an NSNumber, not an array.